# Update a MySQL Database with a Form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a form that allows a user to select a field from a drop down box and then change what is currently written in the field.

My current code allows me to view the drop down list select the field I want to change and then enter my new text into a box. But when I click update, nothing happens.

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("", "", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("") or die(mysql_error()); 

$query = "SELECT * FROM news_updates";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
$i=0;
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$roll[$i]=$rows['Text'];
$i++;
}
$total_elmt=count($roll);
?>
---------------------------------------------------------Now I have the form 
 <form method="POST" action="">
 Select the news post to Update: <select name="sel">
<option>Select</option>
<?php 
for($j=0;$j<$total_elmt;$j++)
{
?><option><?php 
echo $roll[$j];
?></option><?php
}
?>
</select><br />
Text Field: <input name="username" type="text" /><br />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update"/><br />
<input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>
-----------------------------------------------Now I have the update php
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$username=$_POST['username'];
$query2 = "UPDATE news_updates SET username='$username' WHERE rollno='$value'";
$result2=mysql_query($query2) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
echo "Successfully Updated";
}
?>
```

Comment: Warning: **[SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)**. And where is `$value` coming from?

Comment: Please don't delete your question once it's resolved. It might still help other people with a similar problem, so I've rolled back the deletion.

Comment: Stop editing out the question text. If you want to delete the question then do so.

Comment: @TheBlueDog that's not possible since there are upvoted answers already. I voted to close, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak: True, I forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you seem to be missing the `$value` part. Something like this should do, for the last part:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['sel']);
    $query2 = "UPDATE news_updates SET username='$username' WHERE rollno='$value'";
    echo $query2; //For test, to see what is generated, and sent to database
    $result2=mysql_query($query2) or die("Query Failed : ".mysql_error());
    echo "Successfully Updated";
}
?>
```

Also, you should not use **mysql_*** functions as they are deprecated. You should switch to mysqli or PDO.

Comment: The security isn't a main issue for me its just a site I'm using to learn stuff.  I've added your code but still both the 'reset and update' buttons do nothing :(

Comment: Can you add generated html code to your question? I.e. use view source when you open the page, and copy/paste the html code in your question?

Comment: Here is the page source information



<html>
<body>
<php 

    <form method="POST" action="">
    Select the news post to Update: <select name="sel">
    <option>Select</option>
"> Coursework submissions due in Eldon have been delayed untill tomorrow due to building work. All other buildings have not been affected.

</option> <option value="All coursework ."> All .</option> 
 
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update"/><br />
<input name="reset" type="reset" value="Reset"/>
</form>

Comment: I've had to slightly cut down the text in the option fields because of the word limit

Comment: Add it to your question, or use jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
<?php 
for($j=0;$j<$total_elmt;$j++)
{
?><option><?php 
echo $roll[$j];
?></option><?php
}
```

to this

```
<?php 
for($j=0;$j<$total_elmt;$j++)
{
?><option value="<?php echo $roll[$j];?>"> <?php echo $roll[$j];?></option> <?php
}
```

And you also need to change the update query from this

```
$query2 = "UPDATE news_updates SET username='$username' WHERE rollno='$value'";
```

to this

```
$query2 = "UPDATE news_updates SET username='$username' WHERE rollno='".$_POST['sel']."'";
```

**N. B.:** Here I am assuming that `$_POST['sel']` has the value selected by the user from the drop down menu because I could not find anything which corresponds to `$value`

Comment: No way, this will not solve op problems, he's missing something else as well

Comment: I've added these changes and the code still works without errors. but the update and reset buttons still no nothing :(

Comment: @Fabio: I got another error in the code... I edited my answer accordingly... That should make it work, I presume.

Comment: I've made the changes to the update field but this does not solve the problem

Comment: hmm, is it possible that this issue is related to rollno? I've not got it anywhere else in my code

Comment: I have manged to fix part of the error by removing an unused php opener

Comment: From the part of the code that you had put up for perusal those were the 2 things that caught my attention... Anyway rectify those and let me know if it works...

Comment: i now have the error "UPDATE news_updates SET username='ghfghg' WHERE Text='Due to building work anglsea rear exit has now been closed for health and safety reaons. Please use the side exit.'Query Failed : Unknown column 'username' in 'field list'"

Comment: Well the error conveys that there is a non-existent column username in the query... If that is not the case try enveloping username with **`**...

Comment: okay I've changed my code now and I'm getting an entry into the database, but I'm not sure which variable I should be sending. Right now I seem to either get the input "Array" or "3" lol

Comment: $query2 = "UPDATE news_updates SET Text='$?WHATGOESINHERE' WHERE Text='".$_POST['sel']."'";

Comment: But I thought you had this query `$query2 = "UPDATE news_updates SET username='$username' WHERE rollno='$value'";`

Comment: Whoa...!! Why did you remove the question...??

Comment: Oh... Great... So what was the problem...??

Answer (score 0):

First, try adding a value to your options, like so:

```
for($j=0;$j<$total_elmt;$j++)
{
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $roll['id']; ?>"><?php echo $roll['option_name']; ?></option>
<?php
}
```

Then, when you parse your file, go like so:

```
$value = $_POST['sel']; // add any desired security here
```

That should do it for you